# Xslt code for fetching name value basing on the id value given in input

Tags: xml, xslt

Input to the xslt is :

```
<input>
   <id>456</id>
   <class>1</class>
</input>
```

Below is the xml code that is stored in local file and I need to compare the input id value with the id values that are present in the below file and fetch the name value for the relevant id value.

```
<details>
    <data>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>apple</name>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>34</id>
        <name>orange</name>
    </data>
</details>
```

sample XSLT code that I wrote

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:variable name="consumerInfoDoc" select="document('local:///details.xml')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="InputId" select="//id"/>
   <xsl:variable name="Id" select="$consumerInfoDoc/details/information/id/text()"/>
   <xsl:if test="$InputId=$Id">
      <xsl:value-of select=" "/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code that I have written is sample one, please correct it and provide the complete code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:variable name="consumerInfoDoc" select="document('local:///details.xml')"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="inputId" select="id" />
      <xsl:variable name="matchData"
                    select="$consumerInfoDoc/details/data[id = $inputId]" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$matchData/name" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: rishe..thanks for ur reply. I learned new thing in this post..i.e data[id = $inputId].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="consumerInfoDoc" select="document('local:///details.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="/input">
    <xsl:value-of select="$consumerInfoDoc/details/data[id = current()/id]/name"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template matches `/input`(the root element under document node), hence the current node being processed is `input`.
In the XPath in `xsl:value-of` i.e., `$consumerInfoDoc/details/data[id = current()/id]/name`, the first `id`(in the filter expression) is actually `$consumerInfoDoc/details/data/id` and `current()/id` is `/input/id`.
This means that the current node doesn't change with the XPath.. You are comparing the other document's id with the input document's `input/id`..

Comment: murthy... thanks for  your reply. can you pls xplain me this  data[id = current()/id]

Comment: I've done some explanation by editing my answer.. hope it helps